# Why does this compatibility in $k$ imply an entropy inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, information-theory, ergodic-theory

I am working through a book and there's a step that the author makes without any explanation, but I can't seem to figure out how he got this implication. I don't think it's a hard question, if you do not want to read the whole setup scroll to the bottom, and you'll see the inequality in question. Here is the setting:

Let $A$ be a finite alphabet and $x_1^n\in A^n$ a sequence of length $n$. Then one can define a measure on $A^k$, called the circular $k$-type, for a given $k\leq n$ and fixed $x_1^n$ in the following way:

$$p_k(a_1^k|x_1^n)=\frac{|  \{ i\in [1,n]:y_i^{i+k-1}=a_1^k \} |}{n},a_1^k \in A^k$$

Intuitively, twist $x_1^n$ into a loop (so that $x_1$ and $x_n$ are touching, and move a window of length $k$ around the circle and count how many times you see each length $k$ block. Divide that number by $n$ and you have a probability of that block. Trivial example, if that particular $a_1^k$ is not in $x_1^n$ then its probability is $0/n=0$.

This has the following nice property:
$$
p_{k-1}(a_1^{k-1}|x_1^n)=\sum_{a_k \in A} p_k(a_1^k|x_1^n)
$$

For intuition on why this is true, multiply both sides by $n$. Then the left-hand side is the number of times $a_1^{k-1}$ occurs in $x_1^n$, and the right-hand side is the number of times $a_1^{k-1}a_k$ occurs in $x_1^n$ for any $a_k$. These should clearly coincide.

Here is the step that I don't get. Then the author claim that this implies:
$$H^{(k-1)}\leq H^{(i)},i\leq k-1,$$ where $H^{(k-1)},x_1^n$ is the entropy of the $(k-1)$-order Markov chain defined by $P_k(\cdot|x_1^n)$.

Now if I got the right definition here, these should be equal to:
$$
{H}^{(k-1)}  =-\sum_{a_{1}^{k}} \widehat{p}\left(a_{k} \mid a_{1}^{k-1}\right) \widehat{p}\left(a_{1}^{k-1}\right) \log \widehat{p}\left(a_{k} \mid a_{1}^{k-1}\right) 
$$
where $$
\widehat{p}\left(a_{k} \mid a_{1}^{k-1}\right)=\frac{p_{k}\left(a_{1}^{k} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right)}{\sum_{b_{k}} p_{k}\left(a_{1}^{k-1} b_{k} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right)},\widehat{p}\left(a_{1}^{k-1}\right)=\sum_{b_{k}} p_{k}\left(a_{1}^{k-1} b_{k} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right)
$$

Using that nice property above, this simplifies to:

$${H}^{(k-1)}  =-\sum_{a_{1}^{k}} p_{k}\left(a_{1}^{k} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right) \log \frac{p_{k}\left(a_{1}^{k} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right)}{p_{k-1}\left(a_{1}^{k-1} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right)} 
$$
$${H}^{(i)}  =-\sum_{a_{1}^{i+1}} p_{i+1}\left(a_{1}^{i+1} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right) \log \frac{p_{i+1}\left(a_{1}^{i+1} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right)}{p_{i}\left(a_{1}^{i} \mid x_{1}^{n}\right)} ,i\leq k-1
$$

So why does $H^{(k-1)}\leq H^{(i)}$ hold?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try computing $H^{(i)} - H^{(i+1)}$: you should be able to interpret this as essentially a conditional entropy of a two-step forward chain, hence nonnegative (something like $H(X_i, X_{i+1}|X_1^{i-1}),$ which would be non-negative; alternatively, write another marginalisation relation between $p_{i+1}$ and $p_{i-1}$ and use Jensen).

Comment: Thank you @stochasticboy321 very much for your answer! I tried what you suggested, but I think that it probably cannot work, as it's actually a property of this type of circular distribution and does not follow from merely the marginalisation, since one can come up with a "counterexample" to the statement, i.e. distributions which do satisfy the marginalisation but not the entropy inequality (though these distribution are of course not circular k-types of any sequence). Any further ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ah you're quite right. Further what I wrote would even only possibly only make sense for $H^i + H^{i+1},$ so its off on two counts :). Not sure I see it now, I'll try to play with it. Did you explicitly try to work out the edge cases, i.e., to show $H^0 \ge H^1$ or $H^0 \ge H^{n-1}$ or $H^{n-2} \ge H^{n-1}$?

Comment: Hey @stochasticboy321! Yes I tried to show those, but for some reason the inequalities just don't seem to work. I generated a bunch of these in MATLAB and it seems to be true, but I just cannot get the proof. In its most reduced form the question is to show: given a fixed $x_1^n$ show that: $-\sum_{a_1^k} occ(a_1^k) \log \frac{occ(a_1^k)}{occ(a_1^{k-1})}\leq-\sum_{a_1^{k-1}} occ(a_1^{k-1}) \log \frac{occ(a_1^{k-1})}{occ(a_1^{k-2})} $ where $occ(a_1^k)$ is the number of occurrences of $a_1^k$ in $x_1^n$ in the circular sense. But even in this reduced form, I could not get anywhere.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I should probably mention that I do not really need the answer to this anymore, as I avoided having to work with it, however I still think that it's interesting as an example of a trivial-looking problem, which does not seem to have a trivial solution.